# Cout String and int in ternary operator

Tags: c++, string, int

A line in my `c++` code reads:

```
cout<<(i%3==0 ? "Hello\n" : i) ;//where `i` is an integer.
```

But I get this error:

```
operands to ?: have different types 'const char*' and 'int
```

How can I modify the code (with minimum characters)?

Comment: What's the problem using a standard `if-else` statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ugly:

```
i%3==0 ? cout<< "Hello\n" : cout<<i;
```

Nice:

```
if ( i%3 == 0 )
   cout << "Hello\n";
else
   cout << i;
```

Your version doesn't work because the result types of the expressions on each side of `:` need to be compatible.

Comment: Your "more exactly" isn't exact at all -- it's perfectly legal for the type of the second operand to be convertible to the type of the third. ("left" and "right" aren't very useful with the ternary operator)

Comment: @BenVoigt hm, I always thought that the third must be convertible to the second.

Comment: " it is determined whether the second operand can be converted to match the third
operand, and whether the third operand can be converted to match the second operand.  If both can
be converted, or one can be converted but the conversion is ambiguous, the program is ill-formed.
If neither can be converted, the operands are left unchanged and further checking is performed as
described below. If exactly one conversion is possible, that conversion is applied to the chosen operand
and the converted operand is used in place of the original operand for the remainder of this section." 5.16p3

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the conditional operator if the two alternatives have incompatible types. The clearest thing is to use `if`:

```
if (i%3 == 0)
    cout << "Hello\n";
else
    cout << i;
```

although in this case you could convert the number to a string:

```
cout << (i%3 == 0 ? "Hello\n" : std::to_string(i));
```

In general, you should try to maximise clarity rather than minimise characters; you'll thank yourself when you have to read the code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`operator<<` is overloaded, and the two execution paths don't use the same overload.  Therefore, you can't have `<<` outside the conditional.

What you want is

```
if (i%3 == 0) cout << "Hello\n"; else cout << i;
```

This can be made a bit shorter by reversing the condition:

```
if (i%3) cout << i; else cout << "Hello\n";
```

And a few more characters saved by using the ternary:

```
(i%3)?(cout<<i):(cout<<"Hello\n");
```

Comment: Yup, you're right. But is that the reason though? Isn't `i%3==0 ? "Hello\n" : i;` illegal as-is?

Comment: @Luchian: It is illegal, but I'm making a further point that he doesn't want some variant of that that is legal, he really needs two different function calls in the two branches.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << i % 3 == 0 ? "Hello" : std::to_string(i);
```

But, as all the other answers have said, you probably shouldn't do this, because it quickly turns into spaghetti code.